# How can I set html radio value from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

How can I set html radio value from javascript ??
 I try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON("getquestion.php",function(result)
{
        //set radio value
    //$("#choice").html(result.test_choice_a);
    //$("#choice").val(result.test_choice_a);
    //$("#choice").html(result.test_choice_b);
    //$("#choice").val(result.test_choice_b);
    //$("#choice").html(result.test_choice_c);
    //$("#choice").val(result.test_choice_c);
    //$("#choice").html(result.test_choice_d);
    //$("#choice").val(result.test_choice_d);
    document.testform.choice[0].value = result.test_choice_a;
    document.testform.choice[1].value = result.test_choice_b;   
    document.testform.choice[2].value = result.test_choice_c;   
    document.testform.choice[3].value = result.test_choice_d;
}
</script>

<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice" ><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice"><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice"><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice"><br>
```

but it didn't work.

How can I set it ?? help me please.

Comment: There's a missing `);` at the end of your function call.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the content hasn't loaded yet put your ajax call in a `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("getquestion.php",function(result)
    {
            //set radio value
        //$("#choice").html(result.test_choice_a);
        //$("#choice").val(result.test_choice_a);
        //$("#choice").html(result.test_choice_b);
        //$("#choice").val(result.test_choice_b);
        //$("#choice").html(result.test_choice_c);
        //$("#choice").val(result.test_choice_c);
        //$("#choice").html(result.test_choice_d);
        //$("#choice").val(result.test_choice_d);
        document.testform.choice[0].value = result.test_choice_a;
        document.testform.choice[1].value = result.test_choice_b;   
        document.testform.choice[2].value = result.test_choice_c;   
        document.testform.choice[3].value = result.test_choice_d;
    });
});
```

Also element ids should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give an id to many elements

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("getquestion.php", function (result) {
            $("#choice_1").val(result.test_choice_a);
            $("#choice_2").val(result.test_choice_b);
            $("#choice_3").val(result.test_choice_c);
            $("#choice_4").val(result.test_choice_d);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give every radio a uniquie id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("getquestion.php",function(result) {
    //set radio value
    $("#choice_1").val(result.test_choice_a);
    $("#choice_2").val(result.test_choice_b);
    $("#choice_3").val(result.test_choice_c);
    $("#choice_4").val(result.test_choice_d);
}
</script>

<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice_1" ><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice_2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice_3"><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice_4"><br>
```